Is the quasi-particle band gap of a quantum system always non-negative?
The quasi-particle band gap of a system of electrons is defined as
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
E_{\text{gap}} = \varepsilon_{0+}^{QP} - \varepsilon_{0-}^{QP} = E_{0}^{N+1}+E_{0}^{N-1} - 2E_{0}^N,
\end{equation}
where $E^N_0$ is the ground state energy of the system with $N$ electrons, and $\varepsilon_{0+}^{QP} = E_{0}^{N+1} - E_{0}^{N}$ and $\varepsilon_{0-}^{QP} = E_{0}^{N} - E_{0}^{N-1}$ are the (exact) electron addition and removal energies, respectively.
For a non-interacting system, it is easy to show that the gap is always non-negative; In this case, the gap is $E_\text{gap} = \varepsilon_{c} - \varepsilon_v$, where $\varepsilon_c$ and $\varepsilon_v$ are the energies of the lowest unoccupied and highest occupied single-particle states, respectively. As the non-interacting ground state energy is just the sum of the energies of occupied single-particle states, $E_0 = \sum_\text{occ} \varepsilon_i$, it follows that $\varepsilon_c \geq \varepsilon_v$, which means that $E_\text{gap} \geq 0$.
Is the same also true for any interacting system of electrons?
Since the RHS of $(1)$ is equivalent to the finite-difference expression for $\frac{\text{d}^2 E}{\text{d} N^2}$, an equivalent formulation of the question could be: Is the ground state energy of an interacting electronic system always a convex function of the particle number?
Assumptions
I assume that the system is described by the time-independent non-relativistic many-body Hamiltonian
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V_{ee} + V_{en},$$
The nuclei can be treated in the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, and their positions can be taken as fixed parameters in the electronic Hamiltonian, i.e. the nuclei don't move when electrons are added or removed.

IIRC, Eschrig in his DFT book/notes has a section concerning convexity of $E$ as a function of $N$. I don't have time right now to write an answer...

A recent preprint (https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.08632) claims the problem has remained open four Coulomb-type potentials, and that the authors have found a counterexample also for such potentials.

Thanks for the comments @Anyon and @tobias-fünke! Based on that reference, it sounds like the simple proof that I was looking for probably does not exist (yet!)

@JakobKS Yes. If you want, consider to write an answer yourself, possibly summarizing a bit the sources and point out the relevant things. This might help potential future readers.

The expression for bandgap $E_{gap}\sim d^2E/dN^2$ is similar to the expression for inverse compressibility of an electron gas: $1/K=n^2; \partial\mu/\partial N$, where $\mu=\partial E/\partial N$ is the chemical potential. Interestingly, several new research has provided evidence for negative compressibility. For example, take a look at this paper: PRB 96, 075422 (2017)
